# Is there a way to create specific anchor point for a specific keyframe?

Tags: graphics, motion, after-effects, adobe-premiere

I'm a graphic designer new in the motion graphic industry. I'm learning right now and I'm wondering: is there a way to create specific anchor point for a specific keyframe? And not affecting the other keyframes?

I appreciate your help...

Thank you very much!

I've learned how to to move anchor points but if I move the anchor point the other keyframes follow if you have multiple keyframes to one layer